# Angular 9 - Avoiding multiple API calls on typeahead feature

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing a search box that should make a call to an API with the value the user entered. I want to make the call when the user stops typing for some ms.

This works fine for the first request:

```
this.searchForm.get('searchQuery').valueChanges.pipe(
  filter(data => data.trim().length > 0),
  debounceTime(500),
  switchMap( (query: string) => this.productsService.searchProducts(query))
).subscribe();
```

But, if I continue to type it waits for another 500ms and then sends multiple requests (equal to the number of characters typed, for what it seems).

```
productsChanged = new Subject<Product[]>();

  searchProducts(query: string) {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseUrl + '/products/search/' + query)
        .pipe(
          tap(products => {
            this.products = products;
            this.productsChanged.next(this.products.slice());
          }));
   }
```

It will probably be something very simple, but I can't seem to understand what's happening.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w4mbhm

---

**Solution**

I have found the problem.

I was listening to (ngModelChange):

```
  <input
name="searchQuery" 
type="text" 
[(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
(ngModelChange)="onSearch()"
formControlName="searchQuery" />
```

And inside that listener I was appending a new listener to 'valueChanges'. So on each key stroke, a new listener was created.

As expected, a simple mistake, that made me spend some hours.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The first pipe is correct and does what it should be doing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yi2x2a
In the second pipe, you don't need `take(1)` because HTTP calls are completed automatically.
I am afraid `productsChanged.next` does something that may trigger the form

Comment: https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs/

Comment: Your code seems fine-ish. The only way, judging my the code you've posted, where it could go wrong, is that the getting of new products will make your component initialize and subscribe again to the  `searchForm`, basically having multiple subscriptions. It would however require more information as to where you subscribe and how your template looks like. A minimal stackblitz example would be the best

Comment: @TemurTchanukvadze I've added take(1) just to check if it would solve anything. Then I've forgot to remove it. According to your stackblitz, that's how it should work, yes... productsChanged its only a Subject.

Comment: @PoulKruijt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w4mbhm Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I suspected, you are subscribing constantly to your form changes. You should only do this once in your component (or not at all, if you use the `async` pipe):

[working stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ohgqfg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
    searchQuery: new FormControl()
  });

  this.searchForm
    .get("searchQuery")
    .valueChanges.pipe(
      filter(data => data?.trim().length > 0),
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap((query: string) => this.productsService.searchProducts(query).pipe(
        catchError((e) => of([])
      )))
    )
    .subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    });
}
```

You can also do:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.products$ = this.searchForm.get("searchQuery").valueChanges.pipe(
    // ...
  )
}
```

and use the async pipe. This way you don't have to unsubscribe on destroy

Comment: Thanks for showing two alternatives, yes that was it.